# How to convert or import files from Illustrator in Tiled for game development?

Tags: libgdx, tilemap, tiled

I have created all my images for a game in Illustrator, now I want to convert them in Tiled Sheets for developing my game in libGDX. 
So could I import or convert these `.ai` files from Illustrator in Tiled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tiled doesn't currently seem to support .AI files. You need to convert it to a file format Tiled can use as a tileset source, such as .PNG. That can be done by exporting your image as a PNG.